# Indexing bulk data with Elastic Search Javascript API

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

**Background**

In my node application I am trying to index the returned values from an SQL table. I have been reading the docs and I think I should be doing this with the bulk function. I am trying to use the nested data type and I find the documentation to be a little unclear.

There are three functions that come into play here.

> 1. index
> 2. putMapping
> 3. bulk

When I try and add one index it works fine. But when I try and add the bulk indexes it says the index does not exist. This leads me to assume that I need to create the index and then add the nested mappings with `putMapping`. Either way I try I get an error. Most recently I am getting the error,

> "request body is required"},"status":400}',

**Problem**

I am getting this error when I try and create the index which I am trying to do without the body key. I was thinking I needing to create the index with mappings first so I could than enter bulk data. I think my problem is that I am not using the correct functions.

**Example**

*index*

```
exports.createIndex = () => {
    esClient.index({
        index: "products",
        type: "product",
        refresh: "true"
    }, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log('Put Index Error ', error);
        } else {
            this.createMapping();
            console.log('Put Index Response ', response);
        }
    });
};
```

*putMapping*

```
exports.createMapping = () => {
    esClient.indices.putMapping({
        index: "products",
        type: "product",
        body: {
            mappings: {
                product: {
                    properties: {
                        variantId: { type: "text" },
                        productId: { type: "text" },
                        keyStrengths: { type: "text" },
                        something: {
                            type: "nested",
                            properties: {
                                type: { type: "text" },
                                label: { type: "text" },
                                items: {
                                    type: "nested",
                                    properties: {
                                        value: {
                                            type: "text"
                                        },
                                        characteristic: {
                                            type: "text"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log('Put Index Error ', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Put Index Response ', response);
        }
    });
};
```

*bulk*

```
   esClient.bulk({})
```

**Question**

Please tell me the proper way to create a new index, and then bulk insert the data returned from a database. I am not clear if I need to use all three of those functions or where I am going wrong with this.

> My goal is to bulk insert an array of objects that have an array of
>   objects inside of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the right functions. `esClient.index()` is meant to index a document, not to create an index. The correct thing to do in your case is to call [`esClient.indices.create()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-create) in order to create your index with the appropriate mapping and then you can call `esClient.bulk()`. It goes like this:

```
exports.createIndex = () => {
    esClient.indices.create({
        index: "products",
        body: {
            mappings: {
                product: {
                    properties: {
                        variantId: { type: "text" },
                        productId: { type: "text" },
                        keyStrengths: { type: "text" },
                        something: {
                            type: "nested",
                            properties: {
                                type: { type: "text" },
                                label: { type: "text" },
                                items: {
                                    type: "nested",
                                    properties: {
                                        value: {
                                            type: "text"
                                        },
                                        characteristic: {
                                            type: "text"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log('Create Index Error ', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Create Index Response ', response);
        }
    });
};
```

Once that's done, you can call `esClient.bulk()` with your data extracted from the database.

Comment: Thank you for this! If you don't mind, when calling bulk, what is the type in that function? in the example it shows type, text. Would I just call it type nested again or how does it know to use the mapping I previously created?

Comment: I suggest you create another question for the bulk part. Show us how you're doing it.

Comment: Would you mind showing me where this function is in the docs? I can find indices.create but not indices.createIndex(). I keep getting, esClient.indices.createIndex is not a function

Comment: Oops, my bad, the function is called `indices.create` not `indices.createIndex`, sorry about that. I've updated my answer.